# how use .toggleClass() in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello  guys i have this code

```
panelPlusK.append('<div id="foo">click To change the style</div><br>');

$('#foo').click(function() {
    $('.agario-panel').css({
        'background-color': 'rgba(32, 68, 102, 0.72)',
        'color': '#E91E63',
        'border-color': '#2196F3',
    });
    $('.agario-panel input, .agario-panel select').css({
        'background-color': 'rgba(44, 125, 116, 0.55)',
        'color': '#23ff8d',
    });
});
```

i want to make it when i click on it then it changes the style but when i reclick on it again then it remove the style ..i saw toggleClass fuction but i dont know how to implemt it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply move styles to some class and toggle it:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    $('.agario-panel').toggleClass('highlighted');
});
```

Where in CSS you would have something like:

```css
/* default styles of the panel */
.agario-panel {
    background-color: rgba(44, 125, 116, 0.55);
    color: #23ff8d;
}
/* highlighted styles overwrite default */
agario-panel.highlighted {
    background-color: rgba(32, 68, 102, 0.72);
    color: #E91E63;
    border-color: #2196F3;
}
```

As a general advice, avoid [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method for styling elements. In most cases you should better use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) - this way you gain great flexibility when your JS code is independent from CSS styles. Separation of concerns => better code quality, better maintenance.

Comment: @PeterRader I added a note to the answer.

Comment: thanks very much for the answer :) but if i want to change the style of two element ? i edited the post ..i putted same element ..now i correct it .. because `$('#foo').click(function() {
    $('.agario-panel').toggleClass('highlighted');
}); ` thi gonna change style only of agario-panel

Comment: Nothing really changes in this case too. It will just be `$('.agario-panel, .agario-panel input, .agario-panel select').toggleClass('highlighted');`. It's just in CSS you need to define proper styles for `.agario-panel.highlighted {}` and `.agario-panel input.highlighted, .agario-panel select.highlighted { ... }`.

Comment: So I just need to make two css style element exple for.agario-panel :`   gario-panel.highlighted {
    background-color: rgba(32, 68, 102, 0.72);
    color: #E91E63;
    border-color: #2196F3;
}   ` and for agario-panel input, .agario-panel select' input . gario-panel.highlighted, select.agario-panel.highlighted { ... } right?

Answer (score 1):

```
.style {    
   background-color: rgba(32, 68, 102, 0.72);
   color: #E91E63;
   border-color: #2196F3;
   background-color: rgba(44, 125, 116, 0.55);
   color: #23ff8d;
}

$('#foo').click(function() {
   $('element').toggleClass('style');
}
```

This will add the css style to the element when you click on foo. When you click it again, it will remove the style class.

I realize the class may have the wrong styling, but hopefully you get the idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .addClass() and .removeClass()

```js
$( "#foo" ).click(function() {
 $("#foo").addClass("agrario-panel");
});

$( "#remove" ).click(function() {
 $("#foo").removeClass("agrario-panel");
});
```

```css
.agrario-panel { 
        background-color: rgba(32, 68, 102, 0.72);
        color: #E91E63;
        border-color:#2196F3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">Click to change </div>
<div id="remove">Click to Remove</div>
```